# cifs mount is not working

Tags: mount, samba, cifs

I am a bit familiar with linux but I got stucking trying to mount a remote share via CIFS mount.

The remote server is a Zyxel NAS326 and its shares are working under Windows.
Under Ubuntu the mount command

```
mount.cifs //MyNas/drive_p /media/janssen/drive_p -o username=xy,vers=1.0
```

fails with response

`Unable to find suitable address`

Neither

```
smbclient -L //MyNas
```

is working:

```
NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Using file manager (afp) works:

[Connection working using file manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rz0X9.png)

But I want to use cifs mount and if it worked I want to put it into /etc/fstab.
Alas it's not even working when trying to mount the share manually (as user root).

[Output of dmesg after mount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niJ5k.png)

I could not find any hint for return code -111 .
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Uwe

Comment: Hi, try to read this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30054880/what-does-cifs-mount-failed-w-return-code-111-indicate/31557642 may it helps

Answer (score 0):

**Solved** (actually kind of workaround):
The actual reason for the connection error was the NAS' sleeping HDD (Zyxel NAS326).

**Solution:** Wake up the NAS via somehow accessing its HDD (e.g. use the web interface) or do not let it sleep.
Then reboot Ubuntu and the mount works.

**Note:** Without the Ubuntu reboot the mount still does not work (same error code -111).
@AtomiX84: Thanks for the hint, but I already looked up the mentioned thread before my post.

Thanks to all reading my question

Comment: what? I need to reboot? :(